# How to customize folder grouping in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-management, sorting, organizer-software

I wonder, how to customize folder grouping in Win7? You can group them by Name, Date, etc — but how to create custom groups? Like, I have 30 folders on a disk, and i want them to be grouped under custom-made labels like "Wallpapers", which will include several folders, and so on. Can this be achieved with Win7 or any software?

Placing them one into another or using Library is not convenient enough.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it in standard explorer (but you can set additional description or tags to files). Windows don't know what kind of data are on picures, etc. If you are skilled programmer you can write own handler to do it, but is there any sense? You can use any advanced pictures browser for grouping/searching images.

Answer (score 1):

[Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) does this, but only on the desktop.